# CSS triangle/angle based on degree

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I know how to make a pure CSS triangle using borders, but the angle of the triangle is not known.

I want to create an angle image based from some jQuery calculations that output a number (which is an angle).

So:

[image: Flow of what I want to achieve.]

I am open to jQuery obviously since the angle is calculated with it, but if there is some obscure CSS then that'd be preferential!

Comment: I bet there's no way doing it with CSS. Consider using [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Canvas).

Comment: I bet I can do this with 100% CSS.

Comment: @wumm I thought about canvas, I'm just hoping theres a better way. I've already got 3 canvases going already.

Comment: @Indy checkout my answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So though the other answer provides a great bunch of platforms to make triangle angles based on user input, I still felt obligated to work on this and make a workaround that didn't include all the additional graphs.

This is the method I came up with: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pFute

This is the markup:

**HTML**

```
<section>
  <div class="box2"><div class="box"></div></div>
</section>
```

I used `<section>` just to break up the `<div>`, but I'd probably just use 3 `<div>` in production.

**CSS**

```
section {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 200px auto 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
}
.box, .box2 {
    position: absolute;
    background: #000;
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    height: 1px;
    width: 200px;
}
.box {
    bottom:1px;
    background: #F00;
    transform: rotate(-100deg);
}
.box2 {
    bottom: 0;
    right:0;
}
```

Now in `.box` you can change the value of the `rotate` and it will rotate the line to be whatever value.

In my case it comes down to the value that is calculated after the user inputs all of their data.

From this I can inject the `'transform: rotate(-' + VALUE + 'deg);'` via jQuery.

---

**Edit:** This Pen is if you want the angle to be as in my original image: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sjIpx

Answer (score 2):

As i see. You are looking for a visualization using the web. Good idea.

I can suggest you more than a triangle.

Here's a few list of javascript libraries that are very much great for these kind of stuffs.

Below are the links.

- [**D3**](http://d3js.org) - Namely `Data Driven Documents`. Earlier version is named as `Protovis`. With the help you `d3` you can create awesome visualization using the `svg` (scalar vector graphics) elements. It's well documented. Easy to learn and lot of others peoples to help you. Example [**Stack Overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js).
- [**NVD3**](http://nvd3.org/) - Another great library build with the help of d3. Main feature of the NVD3 is that all the charts are very responsive. And using NVD3 is also a best choice. Most of the bar chart, pie chart and normal charts i use is of NVD3 :)

There are more libraries built using d3. You can google it.

If you suggest for jQuery charts. Here are some links.

- [**jqPlot**](http://www.jqplot.com/)
- [**Fusion Charts**](http://www.fusioncharts.com/jquery/)
- [**jChart FX**](http://www.jchartfx.com/)
- [**jQuery Spark Line**](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-about)

But i haven't used of the above libraries except the Spark Line.

And there more other javascript libraries for visualization.

Here's one more i came across while going through the post on Stack Overflow.

[**AM Charts**](http://www.amcharts.com/) - Was seriously amazing with the charts and maps.

You could even try this.

Also try to google for javascript libraries which are even more better for visualization.

Comment: Thanks for these links but they do seem a little big for what I'm intending to do. I mean I haven't delved right in, but I don't want to bloat (and slow loading) when all I need is a simple angle made triangle :)

Comment: @Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhdfgbv - No one will spoon feed you in stack overflow. Everyone here will just help you to deliver what you need only if you try. And for you to try there are open sourced and super flexible java script libraries are available and I've provided the link which i know. Best of luck :)

Comment: After finally looking through all those links these really are the top of the list! Thanks! And hope others will find those links very helpful too!

Comment: :). `d3` is the best if you are looking for visualization through web.

Comment: yeah that's the one I went with :)